# js: method can't access property

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, prototype

Here's what's puzzling me in JavaScript: In the code below, I've got an object constructor containing one property. Below it, I add some prototype methods. The method 'method1' is able to access 'this.property' just fine, and it returns the value 30. The method 'combine' just calls 'method1', but it returns NaN. It seems like 'this.property' was public to the first call but not the second. Why this strange behavior?

```
var ObjBuilder = function()
{
  this.property = 3;
};

ObjBuilder.prototype = function()
{
  var method1 = function()
  {
    return this.property * 10;
  }
  var combine = function()
  {
    return method1() + 2;
  }
  return {method1: method1,
          combine: combine};
}();

// instantiate an object and call its methods
var obj = new ObjBuilder();
console.log(obj.method1());//prints 30
console.log(obj.combine());//prints NaN. WHY???
```

Comment: If you log `this` inside `method1` then call it inside `combine` you'll see the problem

Comment: @t.niese [It doesn't seem like it](https://jsfiddle.net/3ovc6Lye/) - `window`. You've got to call it as `this.method1()` to give `this` context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `combine` simply calls the `method1` function (not `this.method1`, for example), so `this` in `this.property * 10` in that call of `method1` is not bound as you expect and is probably bound to the global object.